# Filter newly selected check boxes and previous selected check boxes in adf

Tags: oracle, checkbox, oracle-adf

I am new in Oracle ADF.
I have made an application in which I can filter all the selected check boxes by Code:
getFilteredRows("SelectRow",true)
Now, I have a requirement to get only those check boxes which are newly ticked/selected and not all of the ticked/selected.
Please help
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Which JDev version do you use?

The only way to know which checkbox has been selected 'newly' is to save the time the checkbox was selected in the row too. Then you can filter the selected rows by selection and time.

Comment: Hi Timo, There is valueChangeListener for Checkbox. I have coded in my bean class to get the new value. It gives me newly selected checkboxes values i.e true/false. Can I code in the same to get the current row attribute ?

Comment: I am using 12.1.3.0.0 version of JDev